# C# Socket Exception - No Connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, sockets, socketexception

I've coded a simple program using sockets. My goal is to connect my pc(which will act as server) to the PC of a friend across the web but my friend, being the client, is receiving back the exception in the title

The connection is done on port 51111, which we both have opened and checked for it being open through cmd trying to run the server program on both PCs and finding 0.0.0.0.51111 as LISTENING by using netstat -a.
We have also disabled the firewall and both client and server are running with administrator privilege on both PCs

The IP in the Client(which was used by my friend on his pc) is the one I(the Server) had at the moment of the test, found by looking on a "My IP" website

Client

```
class Client
{
    public void SocketClient(string request)
    {
        int maxBuffer = 1024;
        try
        {
            IPAddress a = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 2,44,31,207 });
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(a, 51111);

            Socket sender = new Socket(a.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);

                Console.WriteLine("Connected to " + sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
                int bytesSent = sender.Send(message);
                byte[] response = new byte[maxBuffer];
                int bytesReceived = sender.Receive(response);
                Console.WriteLine("Received : " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response, 0, bytesReceived));
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Server

```
class Server
{
    private Socket listener;
    public void SocketServer()
    {
        int maxBuffer = 1024;

        Console.WriteLine("LISTENER STARTED");
        listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 51111));

        listener.Listen(5);
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WAITING FOR CONNECTION");
            Socket socket = listener.Accept();

            string receivedMessage = string.Empty;
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[maxBuffer];
                int bytesReceivedCount = socket.Receive(receivedBytes);
                receivedMessage += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes, 0, bytesReceivedCount);
                if (receivedMessage.IndexOf('\n') > -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Message from Client : " + receivedMessage);
            string reply = ("Message received!");
            byte[] replyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reply);
            socket.Send(replyBytes);
            socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            socket.Close();
        }
    }

    public void ShutDownServer()
    {
        listener.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        listener.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you setup port forwarding on your router?

Comment: Yes I've mentioned that in my question, too.

Comment: I don't see where you specify that in your question, would you mind quoting the part of your question that specifies that you've setup port forwarding? I must be missing something or misunderstanding your wording somewhere.

Comment: "The connection is done on port 51111, which we both have opened"
Sorry if it was cryptic

Comment: Check to make sure IP address is correct.  From cmd.exe try >IPCONFIG/ALL.  It is also possible that a firewall is blocking the port number or another application is already connecting to the server using the same port number.  So you can use cmd.exe >NetStat -a to determine if another application is using the port number.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I took "The connection is done on port 51111, which we both have opened" to mean that your computers had that port open and didn't realize you were saying that the port was open on your router.

Comment: egnomerator No problem! jdweng The IP adress is obtained from a website which tells you your current IPv4. About being sure the port is used by my application I've already did that with the command you mentioned. I've also writed the results in my question.

To summarize in case my whole post was too cryptic

->On both pcs ports are forwarded
->On both pcs firewall is disabled
->On both pcs we're running our side of the thing as administrator

Comment: On the client side, `Socket.Connect()` has an overload that takes an IP string and port number as input: `sender.Connect("207.31.44.2", 51111);` Also, YOUR ROUTER may be forwarding port 51111, but YOUR ISP may be blocking the connection from reaching your router. Some ISPs don't like customers hosting servers without paying extra for it. Talk to your ISP to make sure the connection with your friend is even allowed. Have you tried reversing the roles, having your friend run the server and you run the client?

Comment: Thank you Remy. I'll try both of your suggestions. It'll take a while so in the meanwhile I'll try other things, but I think you have a very good point!